# Java 8 Consumer split by Line

Tags: java, java-8

Can someone tell me how i should use consumers to reach the same output, because this doesn't work ?

```
String names = "John Alex Peter";
String[] namesSplitted = names.split(" ");
for (String s : namesSplitted) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

Consumer<String> cons = x -> System.out.println(x.split(" "));
cons.accept(names);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Consumer` receives input and processes it (i.e. "consumes" it).

A `Consumer<String>` consumes one `String` at a time.

In your code sample, the `Consumer` is `System.out.println`.

You can create a `Stream<String>` from splitting the input `String`, and pass all the elements of this `Stream` to the `Consumer<String>` by calling `forEach()`:

```
Consumer<String> cons = System.out::println;
Arrays.stream(names.split(" ")).forEach(cons);
```

Of course there's no need to separate this snippet into two lines:

```
Arrays.stream(names.split(" ")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 4):

your `Consumer` accept a `String`, but you take a `String[]`.

you can using [Pattern#splitAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) to split a string to let the `Consumer` to accept a `String`, for example:

```
Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(names).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**OR** you can using [String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) or [String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-), for example:

```
Consumer<String> cons =System.out::println;

cons.accept(names.replaceAll(" ","\n"));

//OR
cons.accept(String.join("\n", names.split(" ")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert Array to stream and then use consumer.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    String names = "John Alex Peter";
    String[] namesSplitted = names.split(" ");

    for (String s : namesSplitted) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

   Consumer<String> printConsumer =  System.out::println;
   Arrays.stream(names.split(" ")).forEach( printConsumer);

    // OR Simply
    Arrays.stream(names.split(" ")).forEach( System.out::println);

}
```